# What is the problem with this input? I get segmentation fault(core dumped) in this program

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, segmentation-fault

In this program I get a segmentation fault. If I comment out the last for-loop (which just returns the input parameters) the program runs perfectly, also if I comment the other for-loop (with the abs of numbers) the program still runs perfectly. So maybe the last two loops **together** make some issue?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abs_numbers(int size, int v[], int v2[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    v2[i] = v[i];
    if (v2[i] < 0) {
      v2[i] = v[i] * (-1);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int size;
  int numbers[size];
  int numbers2[size];

  printf("Size of numbers: \n");
  scanf("%d", & size);

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    printf("%d. number: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", & numbers[i]);
  }

  abs_numbers(size, numbers, numbers2);

  printf("Abs of numbers");

  for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
    printf("%d", numbers2[k]);
    if (k < size - 1) {
      printf(", ");
    }
  }
  puts("");

  printf("Numbers: ");

  for (int l = 0; l < size; ++l) {
    printf("%d", numbers[l]);
    if (l < size - 1) {
      printf(", ");
    }
  }
  puts("");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile your program with warnings enabled and fix the problems. With `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g    program.c   -o program` I get `program.c: In function ‘main’:`
`program.c:17:1: warning: ‘size’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`
   `17 | int numbers[size];`

Comment: @Bodo Why does the compiler only throw a warning, but not an error? I thought array size initialization can't be done with non constant variables? And in this case, `size` isn't event initialized?

Comment: As an aside, give variables meaningful names.

Comment: @itzFlubby they are Variable Length Arrays, but you are right that `size` was uninitialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of the array, numbers and numbers2, must be compile time constant.
You can set the size of both array if you can determine the maximum size of them like this.

```
int numbers[16];
int numbers2[32];
```

However, you should dynamically allocate memory if you can not determine the maximum size or if you don't want to waste memory, which requires dynamic allocation like this,

```
int* numbers=malloc(sizeof(int)*16);
int* numbers=malloc(sizeof(int)*32);
```

Don't forget to release the memory you allocated using free().